# More efficient way of merging two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am comparing each element of array with every other element of array and if two elements have the same source/target, target/source I merge the inner array with employees e.g.

```
0=> source - 3 target - 4 officers => 0 - 'Aberdeen Asset Management PLC'
1=> source - 3 target - 4 officers => 0 - 'whatever'
```

it would be merged to

```
0=> source - 3 target - 4 officers => 0 - 'Aberdeen Asset Management PLC', 1 - 'whatever'
```

Here is how the data looks like:

[image]

My code is really inefficient with 1000 on more rows to go through the execution takes about 90 seconds which is unacceptable for this sort of thing.

```
   foreach ($edges as $i => &$edge) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($edges); $j++) {
            if ($edge['source'] == $edges[$j]['source'] && $edge['target'] == $edges[$j]['target']) {
                foreach ($edges[$j]['officers'] as $officer) {
                    array_push($edge['officers'], $officer);
                }
                array_splice($edges, $j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this (**updated**):

```
// we will have new array with officers
$new_items = array();
foreach ($edges as $edge) {
    // create unique keys for `source-target` and `target-source` pairs
    $source_target = $edge['source'] . ':' . $edge['target'];
    $target_source = $edge['target'] . ':' . $edge['source'];

    // check if unique keys exists in `new_items`
    if (!isset($new_items[$source_target]) && !isset($new_items[$target_source])) {
        // if unique key doesn't exist - create a new one
        $new_items[$source_target] = $edge;
    } elseif (isset($new_items[$source_target])) {
        // if unique key exists `$source_target` - add an officer to it
        $new_items[$source_target]['officers'][] = $edge['officers'][0];
    } else {
        // if unique key exists `$target_source` - add an officer to it
        $new_items[$target_source]['officers'][] = $edge['officers'][0];
    }
}

// for returning to numeric indexes use `array_values`
$new_items = array_values($new_items);
```

Comment: @u_mulder well it's much easier if he tells **you** what he needs and then just copy paste. After all, you're doing this for free because you got nothing better to do than produce code so other people can profit from it, why not indulge all their wishes while you're at it? :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `array_search`, `array_keys`, `array_slice` and `array_merge` functions:

```
// an exemplary array
$edges = [
    0 => ['source' => 3, 'target' => 4, 'officers' => ['Aberdeen Asset Management PLC']],
    1 => ['source' => 3, 'target' => 4, 'officers' => ['whatever']],
    3 => ['source' => 4, 'target' => 7, 'officers' => ['Jason']],
    4 => ['source' => 4, 'target' => 5, 'officers' => ['John']],
    5 => ['source' => 4, 'target' => 7, 'officers' => ['Bourne']]
];

foreach ($edges as $k => &$v) {
    $next_slice = array_slice($edges, array_search($k, array_keys($edges)) + 1);
    foreach ($next_slice as $key => $item) {
        if ($item['source'] == $v['source'] && $item['target'] == $v['target']) {
            $v['officers'] = array_merge($v['officers'], $item['officers']);
            unset($edges[$k + $key + 1]);
        }
    }
}

print_r($edges);
```

[DEMO link](https://eval.in/614326)